# How can I bind number of days left into a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, binding

I'm trying to resolve a problem, where I need to count number of days until a due.

I'm using LinqToSql, WPF.

In my Sql, I have some dates (one for each person,(type Date)), that represents the last possible day for something to be paid, for example.

[image]

**My question is, how can I count number of days left for it to be payed, for each person, and then, how can I bind them to my DataGrid?**

[image]

This is my XAML code

```
<DataGrid  Margin="58,0,0,160" Name="dgData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="612" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Ime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lastname" Binding="{Binding Prezime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Days left"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is how I fill my DataGrid

```
ProbaDataContext proba = new ProbaDataContext();
    
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    int nmbDays;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dgData.ItemsSource = proba.Radniks.ToList();

        var sourceList = dgData.ItemsSource as List<Radnik>;
        //this is the only thing i menaged to do, count all the days left
        foreach(var item in sourceList)
        {
            DateTime datum = (DateTime)item.Datum;

            nmbDays = (datum.Date - today.Date).Days;
            txtDatum.Text = nmbDays.ToString();
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

First i had to make sure that my "Datum" type in SQL is DateTime(not date),
then i had to create one more column in my database (place where i will store that number of days, i created it as a varchar since I want to allow it to be negative), and finally i executed those lines of code:

```
dgData.ItemsSource = proba.Radniks.ToList();

            var sourceList = dgData.ItemsSource as List<Radnik>;           
                for(int i=0;i<sourceList.Count;i++)
                {
                    sourceList[i].BrojDana = (sourceList[i].Datum - DateTime.Now).Days.ToString();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an auxiliar child class to fill the datagrid and do the calcs there:

```
    private class AuxRadnik:Radnik
    {
        public int DaysLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.Datum - DateTime.Now).Days;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then change your code to populate de ItemSource correctly:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dgData.ItemsSource = proba.Radniks.Select(r=> new AuxRadnik 
          {Ime = r.Ime, 
           Prezime = r.Prezime, 
           Datum = r.Datum 
          }).ToList();         
}
```

And lastly bind on the XAML part

```
<DataGrid  Margin="58,0,0,160" Name="dgData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="612" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Ime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lastname" Binding="{Binding Prezime}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Days left" Binding="{Binding DaysLeft}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Child class code doesn't seem quite correct, since I get an exception - 'TimeSpan?' does not contain a definition for 'Days' and no accessible extension method 'Days' accepting a first argument of type 'TimeSpan?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you using System on the aux class? (using System;)

Comment: Yes, I do. Let me just clarify, it shows exception in the return line, inside of get.

Comment: Note, this would probobly work if the type was DateTime, not just Date in Sql database.